# How to prevent javascript from running in parallel some code editing the document?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I want to edit a page only with js (no frameworks), so I create some functions, each editing something. In the meantime, I want to obscure the page, so I temporary replace the body with some empty code, call the functions to edit the page, and then set back the original body. My problem is that the result of the functions are showed all at once, so the page is never really "hidden".

Here is the main function I call to do everything.

```
async function blocker() {
    hide(); //replace body 

    ... //some edit

    sleep(5000); //assume I have a function to delay the editing
    unhide(); //put back the original body
}
```

This is the hide function

```
var html;

function hide(){
    html = document.body;
    tempBody = document.createElement('body');
    tempBody.innerText = "LOADING";
    tempBody.style = `...`;
    document.body = tempBody;
}
```

I would expect to see the "LOADING" text immediately after I call `blocker()`, instead, it waits for all the operations to complete and only shows changes after `unhide()` finishes. Could you please help me?

Comment: To start with, have `sleep` return a Promise and `await` it, or put everything after it in a `setTimeout`

Comment: Replace the body? Wouldn't it be easier to nest a block element within body and use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

It will work, without async, await

```
function blocker() {

    hide(); //replace body 

    //some edit

    setTimeOut(function(){

      unhide(); //put back the original body after 5s

    }, 5000);

}
```